# composer not installing laravel project because of the mbstring

Tags: laravel, centos7

i am trying to install laravel project by **composer install** but in return it gives the following error.

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v7.14.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.14.1].
    - laravel/framework v7.14.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for league/commonmark 1.4.3 -> satisfiable by league/commonmark[1.4.3].
    - league/commonmark 1.4.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for facade/ignition 2.0.6 -> satisfiable by facade/ignition[2.0.6].
    - facade/ignition 2.0.6 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  Problem 4
    - Installation request for mockery/mockery 1.4.0 -> satisfiable by mockery/mockery[1.4.0].
    - mockery/mockery 1.4.0 requires php ^7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.24) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 5
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 8.5.5 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[8.5.5].
    - phpunit/phpunit 8.5.5 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  Problem 6
    - Installation request for scrivo/highlight.php v9.18.1.1 -> satisfiable by scrivo/highlight.php[v9.18.1.1].
    - scrivo/highlight.php v9.18.1.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  Problem 7
    - laravel/framework v7.14.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - facade/flare-client-php 1.3.2 requires illuminate/pipeline ^5.5|^6.0|^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.14.1].
    - Installation request for facade/flare-client-php 1.3.2 -> satisfiable by facade/flare-client-php[1.3.2].
```

But mbstring is already installed in php72. First I check the version of the `php --v` and it returned

> PHP 7.2.24

then checked the loaded modules `php72 -m` and there was mbstring no problem there too... After that I checked the `mbstring` is enabled or not `php72 -i | grep mbstring` and it's enabled

> Multibyte decoding support using mbstring => enabled

In the end why composer is not seeing the mbstring? I check the modules of `composer show -p` seeing. And **NO** there is no `mbstring`! Any idea why composer not seeing the mbstring and how can I fix this issue?

Additionally I am in **Centos 7**

Comment: You checked your php version with php -v but then tested for the module using php72, what happens if you test with `php -m`

Comment: I already check that and yes, php72 running https://imgur.com/a/Vr1fFgd @apokryfos

Answer (score 0):

Your mbstring extension is missing for php7.2

Run `sudo apt-get install -y php7.2-mbstring`

**Edit**

Also, mockery/mockery 1.4.0 requires php ^7.3.0.
I suggest upgrading your project php version.

Comment: I mentioned in the question... mbstring installed for the 7.2 up and running

Answer (score 0):

Log speaks for itself.

laravel/framework v7.14.1 requires ext-mbstring

league/commonmark 1.4.3 requires ext-mbstring

facade/ignition 2.0.6 requires ext-mbstring

phpunit/phpunit 8.5.5 requires ext-mbstring

scrivo/highlight.php v9.18.1.1 requires ext-mbstring

try this command

```
yum install php-mbstring
```

then

composer update

Comment: I mentioned in the question too. mbstring is installed on php72 and enabled. please read carefully. and also you can check the php info -> https://imgur.com/a/Vr1fFgd

Comment: ok follow this guide may be help us https://www.linuxfork.com/how-to-install-and-enable-mbstring-php-extension-in-rhel-7-x-centos-7-x/